# jquery sortable accordion should stay closed on drop

Tags: jquery

I have a sortable accordion. When I drop the accordion it opens the dropped section by default. I do not want to open the dropped section rather it should stay closed when I drop any section. Here is my code

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    header: "> div > h3",
    heightStyle: "content",
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    activate: function( event, ui){  
        //this fixes any problems with sorting if panel was open (remove to see what I am talking about)
        if(sorting)
            $(this).sortable("refresh");   
    }
})
.sortable({
    handle: "h3",
    value: "ui-state-highlight",
    start: function( event, ui ){
        //change bool to true
        sorting=true;

        //find what tab is open, false if none
        active = $(this).accordion( "option", "active" ); 

        //possibly change animation here
        $(this).accordion( "option", "animate", { easing: 'swing', duration: 0 } );

        //close tab
        $(this).accordion({ active:false });


        unloadEditors();
    },
    stop: function( event, ui ) {            
$(this).accordion( active, false);
         loadEditors();
        sorting=false;

    },
     update: function(event, ui) {
        var params = $(this).sortable('toArray');
        //alert(params);
        var pageUrl = $("#orderUrl").val();
        dataString = 'ordering='+params;    
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: pageUrl,
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data) {
            //data = jQuery.trim(data);             
        }
        });
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance,

Aisha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by triggering the click event in stop handler. Here is my code

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    header: "> div > h3",
    heightStyle: "content",
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    activate: function( event, ui){  
        //this fixes any problems with sorting if panel was open (remove to see what I am talking about)
        if(sorting)
            $(this).sortable("refresh");   
    }
})
.sortable({
    handle: "h3",
    value: "ui-state-highlight",
    start: function( event, ui ){
        //change bool to true
        sorting=true;

        //find what tab is open, false if none
        active = $(this).accordion( "option", "active" ); 

        //possibly change animation here
        $(this).accordion( "option", "animate", { easing: 'swing', duration: 0 } );

        //close tab
        $(this).accordion({ active:false });


        unloadEditors();
    },
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
ui.item.children( "h3" ).triggerHandler( "click" );
        sorting=false;

    },
     update: function(event, ui) {
        var params = $(this).sortable('toArray');
        //alert(params);
        loadEditors();
        var pageUrl = $("#orderUrl").val();
        dataString = 'ordering='+params;    
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: pageUrl,
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data) {
            //data = jQuery.trim(data);             
        }
        });
    }
});
```